# Adding logic to Python CSV reader

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to parse a "pseudo-CSV" file with the python CSV reader, and am having some doubts about how to add some extra logic. The reason I call it a "pseudo-CSV" file is because ***some*** of the lines in the input file will have text (30-40 chars) before the actual CSV data starts. I am trying to figure out the best way to remove this text.

Currently, I have found 3 options for removing said text:

1. From Python, call grep and sed and pipe the output to a temp file which can then be fed to the csv reader
    (Ugh, I would like to avoid this option)
2. Create a CSV dialect to remove the unwanted text
    (This option just feels wrong)
3. Extend the File object, implementing the next() function to remove the unwanted text as necessary.

I have no control over how the input file is generated, so its not an option to modify the generation.

Here is the related code I had when I realized the problem with the input file.

```
with open('myFile', 'r') as csvfile:
theReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
for row in theReader:
     # my logic here
```

If I go with option 3 above, the solution is quite straight-forward, but 
then I wont be able to incorporate the `with open()` syntax.

So, here is my question (2 actually): Is option 3 the best way to solve this
problem? If so, how can I incorporate it with the `with open()` syntax?

***Edit***: Forgot to mention that Im using Python 2.7 on Linux.

Comment: If your "real" lines are of equal length, you can just compare the `len()` and then slice.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, where are you suggesting I add this logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`csv.reader` accepts an arbitrary iterable besides files:

```
with open('myFile', 'rb') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(filter_line(line) for line in csvfile)
     for row in reader:
         # my logic here
```

Comment: Ok, so then it would just be a simple case of writing the filter_line() function?

Comment: Great, that's a simple and elegant solution. That's why I like Python so much :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [contextlib](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html) and create your own context manager.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def csv_factory(filename, mode="r"):
    # setup here
    fileobj = open(filename, mode)
    reader = mycsv.reader(fileobj)
    try:
        yield reader # return value for usage in with 
    finally:
        fileobj.close() # clean up here


with csv_factory("myFile") as csvfile:
    for line in csvfile:
        print(line)
```

Comment: Where would the logic to remove the unwanted text go? Considering you have `mycsv`, would I also have to modify/extend csv with this solution?